# Setting self as an instance from another class doesn't work [Python]

Tags: python, class, inheritance

Let's assume I have a class A and a class B.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.variable1 = 1
        self.variable2 = 'sometext'

class B:

    def __init__(self, inst):
        self = inst
        print(self.__dict__.keys(), inst.__dict__.keys())
```

The print function returns

```
b = B(inst)
dict_keys(['variable1', 'variable2']) dict_keys(['variable1', 'variable2'])
```

However when I try

```
b.variable1
```

It returns the following error

```
AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'variable1'
```

In my more complex code I need almost all variable from class A in class B.
I tried using class inheritance however I couldn't make it work with class methods and constructors.
Is there a reason why the above method doesn't work?

Thx

Comment: `self` is just a local variable inside `__init__`. Reassigning a variable doesn't make an object into another object. Why do you need `B` if you just want an instance to be the same as an instance of `A`?

Comment: I 'm trying to avoid editing A as it is an old class for basic variable/operations and a lot of my code depends on it.

Comment: Then use composition, as mentioned [by Zephyrus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75184286/1126841).

Comment: What is `inst`? Did you mean: `class B(A):`? (with a more suitable `__init__()`?)

Comment: sry forgot to mention inst is an instance of class A

Comment: It seems like there is a lot you forgot to mention. You could show us what went wrong with using inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to overwrite self, but that only works while you're in the init. Instead, try assigning the `inst` to a variable of the class B:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, inst):
        self.inst = inst
        print(self.__dict__.keys(), inst.__dict__.keys())
```

Now you can access the variables of class A via:

```
inst = A()
b = B(inst)
b.inst.variable1
```

Not sure what you're trying to achieve here exactly, but you could also initiate the class A object inside the init of class B instead of passing the object to class B.

Answer (score -1):

To use variable from class A in B you have to access to class A from B. Then execute class B

```
class A:
    variable1 = 1
    variable2 = 'sometext'

class B:
    def __init__(self, inst=None):
        self.f1 = A().variable1
        self.f2 = A().variable2
    def get_var(self):
        print (self.f1)

B().get_var()
```